# Differential Calculus Question

Tags: calculus

I can do the first two parts(r=1,r=3) but I don't know how to evaluate the last part without induction.
What is the meaning of that "delta" in the last part?
It is a tripos question

[image]

Comment: What is the name of this book?

Comment: it's from a old mathematical tripos exam paper

Comment: How to prove it for "r"

Comment: Can you send me link of the book?

Comment: it's [TRIPOS](http://archive.org/details/mathematicalprob00wolsuoft)

Comment: Please help to find an answer for this question